# Django - Edit Or Delete Selected Rows In A Table

Tags: django

I'm trying to select one or multiple items in my table to do some manipulations, such as deleting the selected rows all at once. I want to keep it simple and do everything in html. I'm struggling to pass the status of each checkbox through my POST request. In my views, this is what request.POST returns:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['mtoFZt1PvlnAsYgEjT...'], 'selection': ['on', 'on', ...]}>
```

How can I access the ID and value of each checkbox in the POST request? Am I missing something in my template?

**Template**

```
<form method="post" action="/products/delete">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Order #</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        {% for product in product_list %}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id={{product.id}} name="selection"></td>
            <td>{{product.id}}</td>
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td>{{product.price}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the product id in the field name, then extract it in the backend

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selection_{{product.id}}" />
```

Then in the backend

```
selected_ids = [box[9:] for box in request.POST.keys() if box.startswith("selected_")]
```

Comment: Yep that works, exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks! Any idea how I would go about having multiple input buttons in this form, like 'Delete', 'Update', 'View'?

Comment: Implement multiple views like this one, then create link buttons from the detail page to the update or delete page. 
Happy to hear it solved your problem, can you please upvote and mark as answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.